# Compare today's Date with CSV and send out an email if expired

Tags: powershell

Can anyone show me how can I do in order to compare date in CSV files and send out a reminder email using PowerShell? 
Thanks.

Regards,
Looi

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to help you can you please provide a little more information (e.g what is the format of the date in the CSV) and ideally some code showing what you have tried to do to solve this so far. If you haven't already, it may be worth reading the getting started guide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing this might be the answer.

```
# Just imitating Import-Csv here...
$csv = "Text,Date",
       "Abc,6/10/2017",
       "Def,3/26/2017",
       "Uvw,2/5/2017 ",
       "Xyz,2/13/2017" | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Get the date in a sortable form and filter:
$out = $csv | Select-Object -Property Text,
                                      @{Name="Date"; Expression={Get-Date $_.Date}} |
              Where-Object {$_.Date -lt (Get-Date 3/1/2017)}

# If any are earlier than 3/1/2017, send email:
if ($out)
{
    # I'm outputting strings that look like the Send-MailMessage cmdlet...
    $out | ForEach-Object {
        "Send-MailMessage -To      `"Usr <usr@grandwazzoo.com>`"
                          -From    `"$($_.Text) <$($_.Text)@grandwazzoo.com>`"
                          -Subject `"A Reminder`""
    }
}
```